# mongoose 7.0.3 strict search on date with operator $and

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the problem with my query. I have objects in my collection with subfield `start_date`. And I need strict search on that date.  As part of constructing my query I use `$and` operator so the final query looks like:

```
// I've tried this
 wb_collection_tracking_for_testing.countDocuments({ '$and': [ { 'CurrentState.start_date': '2021-07-01T00:00:00' } ] }, {})
// and this
wb_collection_tracking_for_testing.countDocuments({ '$and': [ { 'CurrentState.start_date': '2021-07-01' } ] }, {})
// and this
wb_collection_tracking_for_testing.countDocuments({ '$and': [ { 'CurrentState.start_date': new Date( '2021-07-01') } ] }, {})
```

and they all give zero with mongoose 7.0.3. But at least the last one gives the right result in `mongosh`. So my question is How to use strict search with dates on subfields with usage of operator `$and`?

UPD: The example of the object in the collection (I've included only related to this query fields) `start_date` is stored as `Date` in mongoDB:

```
{ CurrentState: { start_date: 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 }}
```

Field `start_date` is not presented in the schema (it is created with a `strict: false` option). But I've tried to add this field to the schema with type `Date` and I've got the same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you specify a timezone somewhere in the node.js code?

Comment: No I don't use timezones

Comment: What do you mean by strict search ? and can you add the schema and an example of the data you have in the collection ?

Comment: By strict search I mean seach for the exact same date as I entered. If I entered 2021-07-01T00:00:00 I should find only objects with this date. And I've updated the question.

Comment: what about `'CurrentState.start_date': new Date('2021-07-01T00:00:00')` and `'CurrentState.start_date': new Date('2021-07-01T00:00:00Z')` ?

Comment: 'CurrentState.start_date': new Date('2021-07-01T00:00:00Z') this one with timezone works,  thanks. Please make an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MongoDB stores times in UTC](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/model-time-data/#model-time-data), so you have to convert your date using [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) for example or a string representing the UTC time zone:

```
const myDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 06, 01)); // month index starts from 0
// Or
// const myDate = new Date('2021-07-01T00:00:00Z');

const result = await wb_collection_tracking_for_testing.countDocuments({ '$and': [ { 'CurrentState.start_date': myDate } ] }, {})
```